# Add some px to a "scroll to position" function

Tags: jquery

I have a fixed header bar that works with anchor links to scroll through the page. The links from the header bar gets active if you are on the position. 
Basicially the active class comes 75px to late, because the fixed header is 75 px height.

How can I add some extra px to the function to compensate that?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    
    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.light-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#menu-center {
    width: 980px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-center ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}
.active {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
a {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#home {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(images/home-bg2.png);
}
#portfolio {
    background-image: url(images/portfolio-bg.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#about {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#contact {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1 menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then I guess you just need to compensate it by following line:

```
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop() + $("#menu-center").height(); //adjusting the scrollPos as per menu height
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //smoothscroll
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
      menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
    }, 500, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
      $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
  });
});

function onScroll(event) {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop() + $("#menu-center").height(); //adjusting the scrollPos as per menu height
  
  $('#menu-center a').each(function() {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > (scrollPos)) {
      $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
      currLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
      currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.light-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#menu-center {
  width: 980px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-center ul {
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-center ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  display: inline;
}
.active {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}
a {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}
#home {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(images/home-bg2.png);
}
#portfolio {
  background-image: url(images/portfolio-bg.png);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#about {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#contact {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1 menu">
  <div id="menu-center">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```